# Function to get content of a bash variable

Tags: python

I have files where bash string variables are gradually appended:

```
URI += "path \
     path \
     path \
"
<some other code>

#URI += "path"

URI += "path \
     path"
```

As you may notice there are different way of appendings, partly over several lines. There is other code as well in those files.

Now I tried to write a function which gets the content of the variables (everything between the quotes):

```
def grepVar(filepath, var):
    list = []
    with open(filepath, "r") as file:
        for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if var in line:
                if line.count('"') is 2:
                    list.append(line)

# until here it works for "URIs" over 1 line

                else:
                    num = num + 1
                    while(line.count('"') is 0):
                        list.append(line)
                        num = num + 1
    return list

print grepVar(path, "URI")
```

So In the `else` condition I try to raise the loop manually and append all lines until another quote would appear (`while`-loop). I am not sure if I can tie on this idea or if I have to discard it completely. In this case could you pls give me hints how to solve my problems? I am not sure if I described it well since its kind of specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `line` if given through a higher level `for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):` loop, you cannot use a `while (line...)` inside that loop.

A common way to solve this problem is to save state between lines. You function could become (I removed `num` management because I could not understand the requirement):

```
def grepVar(filepath, var):
    lst = []
    inquote = False
    with open(filepath, "r") as fil:
        for num, line in enumerate(fil, 1):
            if inquote:
                lst.append(line)
                if line.count('"') > 0:
                    inquote = False
            elif var in line:
                if line.count('"') == 2:
                    lst.append(line)
                else:
                    lst.append(line)
                    inquote = True
    return lst
```

You should also avoid to use standard Python words such as `list` of `file` for your own variables, because the hide the standard meanings.

Comment: Regarding the avoidance of standard Python words: Is it bad because of readability (naming conventions) or can you get real problems with it? I agree with you but in many tutorials they just use "list" or "file" as variables. Got this habit from those probably, but will try to heed your proposal :-)

Comment: Another comment ... I think in 7th line (`lst.append(line)` you did the wrong indentation

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355: Edited... Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: The "elif" has to be a simple "if", too. :-) The rest is perfect

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355: Oups, there was an indentation error but it was on next line! And `elif` **must** be `elif` (but related to previous if): either inquote: some processing or outside: another one.

Comment: Yes now its easier to understand, I changed it too, but I think if you change elif to if it works in any case. For me it did - onyl without the new indentation of course

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355: Beware, if last *inquote* line was `as YOURI did"` you will append it once because of inquote, and if you have a simple `if` instead of `elif`, you will find `"URI"` in the line and add it a second time. Worse, you will reset `inquote` to True... Yes corner cases are hmm... corner cases...

Comment: OK thats true, however in my example the key_woards from var cant occur in another way, but you couldn't know that from the example. but to get very sure i changed the last `else:` to `elif line.count('"') == 1` since there is no way that there is URI without any quote in the same line